# UIWebView get request URL path (html string)

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am able to load a HTML string into the `UIWebView` with CSS obtained from an online source. The problem I have now is to get the path of the link that was clicked. If I use this:

`webView.loadHTMLString(finalHtml, baseURL: baseUrl)`

I get the path clicked to be "/" when I `println(webView.request?.URL.path)` in the `UIWebViewDelegate` `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`.

If I use this:

`webView.loadHTMLString(finalHtml, baseURL: nil)`

I get "nil" when I `println(webView.request?.URL.path)`

Of course, I have set the `baseURL` to be the original website, but from my understanding, if the link has the full address, the `baseURL` is irrelevant.

Any pros out there with any advice on how to get the actual path that is indicated in the  tags of the link that was clicked? Thank you in advance =D

**EDIT** When I long click the link, there will be a popup with the correct link shown. I have tried everything, including `absoluteString`, but I still won't get the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that it eluded everyone's eyes that I made a silly mistake in my code. Instead of `webView.request?.URL.path`, I should use `request.URL.path`. Really small thing that caused me so much agony. So in case anyone is as silly as me, in your `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`, use `request` instead of `webView.request`.

Answer (score 1):

If `webView.loadHTMLString(finalHTML, baseURL: baseURL)` and `println(webView.request?.URL.path)` are called in the same code block, the `webView` won't have a non-nil `request` property yet, and so you can't get the URL path on that request.  `UIWebView` is loading your HTML string asynchronously.  You can implement `UIWebViewDelegate` to see when a link is tapped in your `UIWebView`.  Use the following delegate method:

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    if navigationType == .LinkClicked {
        println(request.URL.path)
    }
    return true
}
```

Leave out the `if navigationType == .LinkClicked` conditional if you want to see the path of all requests including navigation backwards, forwards, etc.

Comment: Of course I already implemented this `UIWebViewDelegate` to check the path. It just isn't working

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/) for NSURL.

Besides path, there is a property `absoluteString` that includes the host, base URL etc.

Comment: Doesn't work. Just tried. Now I either get the full URL when I use a `baseURL`, or I get "about:blank" when I use nil

Comment: And that is after clicking a link on the website? What content does the page actually load?

Comment: Yes. That is after I click a link. It is just a normal html page with links. No javascript at all